# Jquery drag and drop upload without actual upload

Tags: jquery, plugins, drag-and-drop

I am looking for a JQuery plugin that allows me to drag files into a div or something and then sends the filename to my backend application (java).

Most plugins I find upload the file, but I want the filenames of moviefiles (4GB+ in size) so the upload part isn't a wanted function.

So to recap:
Upload div on html page where a user can drop a movie file (mkv or avi) and then a plugin sends the filename of the dropped file to my java backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plugin. Here's a quick script that will get the names of files dragged into a div:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfTfR/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#dropper').on('dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    })

    $('#dropper').on('dragenter', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    })

    $('#dropper').on('drop', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            $('#fileList').append('<ul>' + files[i].name + '</ul>');
            // use ajax to send the filenames off to your server here
        }
    });
});
```